# VideoJS: mp4 is not working when dynamically changing the video url

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html, coffeescript, video.js

I am using videoJs for showing the video.

HTML

```
<video id="player-vjs_html5_api" class="vjs-tech" crossorigin="anonymous" preload="auto" src="http://path-to-video/small.mp4">
  <p class="vjs-no-vjs">Your browser does not support video.</p>
</video>
```

Javascript

```
  loadMedia: function(path) {
    player.src(path);
    return void 0;
  }
```

It works perfectly when i used `.webm` but i tried with `mp4` i got following error

```
VIDEOJS: ERROR: (CODE:4 MEDIA_ERR_SRC_NOT_SUPPORTED) The media could not be loaded, either because the server or network failed or because the format is not supported.
```

I tried following too but it doesn't work

```
<video id="player-vjs_html5_api" class="vjs-tech" crossorigin="anonymous" preload="auto">
    <source src="" type="video/mp4" />
    <source src="" type="video/webm" />
    <source src="" type="video/ogv" />
  <p class="vjs-no-vjs">Your browser does not support video.</p>
</video>
```

and

```
  loadMedia: function(path) {
    player.src([
        { type: "video/mp4", src: path+".mp4" },
        { type: "video/webm", src: path+".webm" },
        { type: "video/ogg", src: path+".ogv" }
    ]);
    return void 0;
  }
```

but it didn't work too.

Comment: Do you have an example of an MP4 that doesn't work?

Comment: @misterben : it worked when i removed the `crossorigin="anonymous"` please let me know if it affect somewhere else.

Answer (score -1):

It works when i did following changes. just removed `crossorigin="anonymous"`

```
<video id="player-vjs_html5_api" class="vjs-tech" preload="auto">
    <source src="" type="video/mp4" />
    <source src="" type="video/webm" />
    <source src="" type="video/ogv" />
  <p class="vjs-no-vjs">Your browser does not support video.</p>
</video>
```

javascript

```
loadMedia: function(path) {
    player.src([
        { type: "video/mp4", src: path+".mp4" },
        { type: "video/webm", src: path+".webm" },
        { type: "video/ogg", src: path+".ogv" }
    ]);
    return void 0;
  }
```